# OpenGL Viewing fault

Tags: opengl, 3d

I have created a 3D room by using `gluLookAt` function inside a 3D cube to get the room feel. Inside the room I am rotating a cube and it works fine till here.

But the moment I add a sphere inside the room the 3D view of the room disappears and only plain background is seen with the cube and sphere.

My code :

```
void cube() {

glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT, qaBlue);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE, qaBlue);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR, qaWhite);
glMaterialf(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SHININESS, 60.0);

glRotatef(_angle, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);        // Draw The Cube Using quads
//glColor3f(0.0f, 0.25f, 0.0f);    // Color Blue
glNormal3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glVertex3f(0.25f, 0.25f, -0.25f);    // Top Right Of The Quad (Top)
glVertex3f(-0.25f, 0.25f, -0.25f);    // Top Left Of The Quad (Top)
glVertex3f(-0.25f, 0.25f, 0.25f);    // Bottom Left Of The Quad (Top)
glVertex3f(0.25f, 0.25f, 0.25f);    // Bottom Right Of The Quad (Top)
//glColor3f(0.25f, 0.5f, 0.0f);    // Color Orange
glNormal3f(0.0, -1.0, 0.0);
glVertex3f(0.25f, -0.25f, 0.25f);    // Top Right Of The Quad (Bottom)
glVertex3f(-0.25f, -0.25f, 0.25f);    // Top Left Of The Quad (Bottom)
glVertex3f(-0.25f, -0.25f, -0.25f);    // Bottom Left Of The Quad (Bottom)
glVertex3f(0.25f, -0.25f, -0.25f);    // Bottom Right Of The Quad (Bottom)
//glColor3f(0.25f, 0.0f, 0.0f);    // Color Red
glNormal3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glVertex3f(0.25f, 0.25f, 0.25f);    // Top Right Of The Quad (Front)
glVertex3f(-0.25f, 0.25f, 0.25f);    // Top Left Of The Quad (Front)
glVertex3f(-0.25f, -0.25f, 0.25f);    // Bottom Left Of The Quad (Front)
glVertex3f(0.25f, -0.25f, 0.25f);    // Bottom Right Of The Quad (Front)
//glColor3f(0.25f, 0.25f, 0.0f);    // Color Yellow
glNormal3f(0.0, 0.0, -1.0);
glVertex3f(0.25f, -0.25f, -0.25f);    // Top Right Of The Quad (Back)
glVertex3f(-0.25f, -0.25f, -0.25f);    // Top Left Of The Quad (Back)
glVertex3f(-0.25f, 0.25f, -0.25f);    // Bottom Left Of The Quad (Back)
glVertex3f(0.25f, 0.25f, -0.25f);    // Bottom Right Of The Quad (Back)
//glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.25f);    // Color Blue
glNormal3f(-1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glVertex3f(-0.25f, 0.25f, 0.25f);    // Top Right Of The Quad (Left)
glVertex3f(-0.25f, 0.25f, -0.25f);    // Top Left Of The Quad (Left)
glVertex3f(-0.25f, -0.25f, -0.25f);    // Bottom Left Of The Quad (Left)
glVertex3f(-0.25f, -0.25f, 0.25f);    // Bottom Right Of The Quad (Left)
//glColor3f(0.25f, 0.0f, 0.25f);    // Color Violet
glNormal3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glVertex3f(0.25f, 0.25f, -0.25f);    // Top Right Of The Quad (Right)
glVertex3f(0.25f, 0.25f, 0.25f);    // Top Left Of The Quad (Right)
glVertex3f(0.25f, -0.25f, 0.25f);    // Bottom Left Of The Quad (Right)
glVertex3f(0.25f, -0.25f, -0.25f);    // Bottom Right Of The Quad (Right)
//glScalef(10.0,2.0,2.0);
glEnd();

}

void sphere(){
    glPushMatrix();
    glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0);
    //glRotatef(_angle/10, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glTranslatef(-2.0,0.0,0.0);
    glutSolidSphere(0.25,70,70);
    glPopMatrix();
}



void display() {

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -10.5);
gluLookAt(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
wall();
cube();
sphere();
glFlush();
//glutSwapBuffers();
}

void animation(int value) {
    _angle += 2.0f;
    if (_angle > 360) {
        _angle -= 360;
    }
    glutPostRedisplay(); //Tell GLUT that the scene has changed
    glutTimerFunc(25, animation, 0); //call animation again in 25 milliseconds
}

void myReshape(int x, int y) {
    if (y == 0 || x == 0)
        return;  //Nothing is visible then, so return
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(40.0, (GLdouble) x / (GLdouble) y, 0.5, 20.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glViewport(0, 0, x, y);  //Use the whole window for rendering
}
void init(void) {
    glClearColor(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.0);
    glLightModeli(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_LOCAL_VIEWER, GL_TRUE);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    GLfloat qaAmbientLight[] = { 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f };
    GLfloat qaDiffuseLight[] = { 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1.0f };
    GLfloat qaSpecularLight[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
    glPushMatrix();
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, qaAmbientLight);
    glPopMatrix();

}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(750, 700);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutCreateWindow("Zero Gravity Room");
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(myReshape);
    glutTimerFunc(25, animation, 0);  //Set the function for the animation.
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "But the moment I add a sphere inside the room the 3D view of the room." What happens then?

Comment: @derhass Sorry, I forgot to add that part. I edited the question.

Comment: You should  also paste the source code for your drawing functions.

Comment: @derhass I added the code for small cube inside the room and the sphere